# Preg_quote the orignal string and then stripslashes from the output string

Tags: php

How can I preg_quote the string and then strip slashes in the output string?

My string has multiple new lines and I want to display newlines as 1.2.3 etc

The example String :

```
Catch all pattern ^(.*)$
Catch limited char ^([^a-d]+)
```

I want to display it as

```
1. Catch all pattern ^(.*)$

2. Catch limited char ^([^a-d]+)
```

What changes do i need to do in my code so that it can first escape the special chars in the string then display the new string   ?

```
  echo "<ol start='1'>" . preg_replace("/^(.*?)$/m", "<li>$1</li>", $str) . "</ol>";
```

Comment: did my answer fix your problem? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a function:

```
function output($str){
    return '<ol><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $str) . '</li></ol>';
}
```

and then using the function to output it on the page

```
<?php
    output($str);
?>
```

The output should be:

```
1. Catch all pattern ^(.*)$

2. Catch limited char ^([^a-d]+)
```